# detecting and skipping double quotations in JSON data in Android App

Tags: android, json

So, I am trying to retrieve JSON data from a webservice. It usually works. It doesn't work, however, if the value of a certain variable has double quotations as part of its content. For example, if I am parsing this data:

```
{"ID":"1057","PlaceTitle":"Place 1","PlaceDetails":"George Bush once said "This is the best dang place in the world""}
```

I get an error on "George bush... because it is trying to detect it as a variable because of the quotes, I believe. This exception is thrown:

```
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 1418 of
```

So what I want to do is "if this exception is thrown, treat it as content within PlaceDetails, and continue on." Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Code:

```
try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                final JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                try {
                    arrayOfLocationss.add(new Location(context,
                            json.getInt("ID") json
                                    .getString("PlaceTitle"), json
                                    .getString("PlaceDetails"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: The problem is that it's not valid JSON. If you control the webservice that returns the data, fix it by using a real JSON encoder rather than assembling things by yourself. If you don't, tell them to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the webservice so it returns properly formatted JSON.  Quotes inside of strings need to be escaped with a backslash:

```
{"ID":"1057","PlaceTitle":"Place 1","PlaceDetails":"George Bush once said \"This is the best dang place in the world\""}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you escape all double quotes when you use `getString`? Try something like

```
arrayOfLocationss.add(new Location(context,
      json.getInt("ID") json
            .getString("PlaceTitle").toString().replaceAll("\"", "\\\""), 
            json.getString("PlaceDetails").toString().replaceAll("\"", "\\\""));
```

Comment: a) I don't believe that escapes the quotes but rather removes them. b) even if it did, it would escape those that are part of the regular JSON syntax as well, which would not be more valid than the original.

Comment: @jcaron, you are absolutely right. Updating my answer.